# using barcode value to lookup drug information

Tags: openfda

I am trying to build a query tool that takes a scanned barcode (NDC) and looks up the drug information in the openFDA.    I have a package for Latanoprost Ophthalmic Solution with a package code of 2420846325, which I think translates to 24208-463-25.  Using Postman with my api-key, I submit a GET such as: 
https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?api_key=&search=product_ndc:24208-463-25

However, this returns the product "Carvedilol" and not Latanoprost like I would expect.

When I use the Search page (https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/ndc/index.cfm), selecting the "NDC Code" type from the drop down menu and providing 24208-463-25 for the code, I get the results I was looking for.  I do notice that the online query returns a product ndc value of 24208-463 which returns the correct result when I use it in my GET call.

I am hoping you can tell me if the package code is being ignored with the online tool and should I also drop that package code when I make my API calls?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can search with the package code using the below query (packaging.package_ndc). Below query return the results including package code.

> ### https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:24208-463-25

If you want to search only by product ndc code excluding the package code use the below query.

> ### https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:24208-463

Both the queries return the results for the drug *latanoprost*.
You can find more details about the searchable fields for NDC directory here (https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/ndc/searchable-fields)

Comment: The problem that I am running into is that scanning the barcode gives me the value 2420846325 and so I am looking for an algorithm to determine if that should be 4-4-2, 5-3-2, or 5-4-1  format to submit to the API.

Comment: When I scan the packaging I get _{"format":"UPC_A","text":"324208463253"}'_ . I see that I can disregard the first ('3') and last ('3') values, but that still leaves the problem of knowing how to parse 2420846325 into either a product or package NDC value.